# Zend form validation - NotEmpty + StringLength

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework

In form element, I have edited error messages:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'type', array(
    'label' => 'Type: ',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'placeholder' => 'type',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('min' => 3, 'max' => 10, 'messages' => array('stringLengthTooShort' => 'The type is too short.', 'stringLengthTooLong' => 'The type is too long.')))
        ,array('validator' => 'NotEmpty', 'options' => array('messages' => array('isEmpty' => 'Type is required.')))
    ),
));
```

Problem is, if I send empty form, both messages will show up (The type is too short + Type is required.). But in this case, I need to show up only NotEmpty error message and not Stringlength (min length 3) error message. So I need to validate minlength after NotEmpty validation. Thanks

**EDIT**:
i have tried changing diferent positions of calling required and validators and diferent settings of their chains true/false (next code), but it still shows me both error messages if element is empty

```
$this->addElement('text', 'type', array(
    'label' => 'Type: ',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'placeholder' => 'type',

    'validators' => array(
        array('validator' => 'NotEmpty',true, 'options' => array('messages' => array('isEmpty' => 'Type is requiredDDDD.'))),
        array('validator' => 'StringLength',false, 'options' => array('min' => 3, 'max' => 10, 'messages' => array('stringLengthTooShort' => 'The type is too short.', 'stringLengthTooLong' => 'The type is too long.')))

    ),
    'required' => true,

));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

1. Comment the second validator

   ```
   $this->addElement('text', 'type', array(
       'label' => 'Type: ',
       'class' => 'form-control',
       'placeholder' => 'type',
       'required' => true,
       'validators' => array(
           //array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('min' => 3, 'max' => 10, 'messages' => array('stringLengthTooShort' => 'The type is too short.', 'stringLengthTooLong' => 'The type is too long.'))),
           array('validator' => 'NotEmpty', 'options' => array('messages' => array('isEmpty' => 'Type is required.')))
       ),
   ));
   ```
2. and add the validator in the `isValid()` function:

   ```
   public function isValid($data) {

       $etat_valid = parent::isValid($data);

       $error = $this->getElement('type')->getMessages();
       if (empty($error)){
           $validator = new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array( 
                'min' => 3, 
                'max' => 10, 
                'messages' => array('stringLengthTooShort' => 'The type is too short.', 
                                    'stringLengthTooLong' => 'The type is too long.')
                                                     )
                                              );

           $etat_valid_type = $validator->isValid($data['type']);
           if (!$etat_valid_type){
                  $this->getElement('type')->addErrors($validator->getMessages());
           }
       }  

       return $etat_valid && $etat_valid_type;
    }
   ```

Comment: Thx for reply, but where should I put your isValid function (probably controller?) and when and how to call it? I validate my whole form in controller by classic way:     if ($form->isValid($formData))

Comment: IsValid function is a zend form function, so put it in your form

Comment: and it will be called automatically in your controller with $form->isValid(...)

Comment: Works perfect, thx for that. But StringLength validator shows original Zend error messages, and not new edited messages so I removed messages from validator and in next line I added $validator->setMessages.... And how to do same think, if I want to use notEmpty+StringLength validators on more elements in same form but with diferent StringLength validators (mean diferent values for min/max  for each element)?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for my last comment, how to add NotEmpty + diferent StringLength validators for more elements in same form:

```
public function isValid($data) {
    $etat_valid = parent::isValid($data);
    $elements = Array(Array('name', 4, 9), Array('type', 3, 10), Array('type2', 2, 12));

    for ($index = 0; $index < count($elements); $index++) {
        $error = $this->getElement($elements[$index][0])->getMessages();
        if (empty($error)) {
            $validator = new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array(
                'min' => $elements[$index][1],
                'max' => $elements[$index][2],
                    )
            );
            $validator->setMessages(array(
                Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>
                'Too short: min '.$elements[$index][1].' chars.',
                Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG =>
                'Too long: max '.$elements[$index][2].' chars.'
            ));
            $etat_valid_type = $validator->isValid($data[$elements[$index][0]]);
            if (!$etat_valid_type) {
                $this->getElement($elements[$index][0])->addErrors($validator->getMessages());
            }
        }
    }
    return $etat_valid && $etat_valid_type;
}
```

So thx for your answers Doydoy

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your return, glad you found your solution, but I think that there is a small bug: the variable `$etat_valid_type` is overwritten at each iteration of the loop, so it's the last one is returned. Good luck :)

Comment: Yes, you right Doydoy. Now i see also that my solution is not fully working. Trying to fix, but still with no success. Do you have any idea how to handle  more validators? Thx

Comment: Your solution seems good, try with another `$etat_valid_type` variable. for example before loop for :`$etat_valid_type1 = true;`   and in the loop: `$etat_valid_type2 = $validator->(...);` `if (!$etat_valid_type2){$etat_valid_type1 = false; $this->getElement(...)..}` and after loop :`return $etat_valid && $etat_valid_type1;` Good Luck :)

Comment: Ok, thx for your patience with me. Ill try figure something with your advice and Ill give some response. My main problem is, that i dont fully understand validators and dont know how to debug those variables so im trying by method attempt, mistake...